# Collections.singleton() methods does not work as documentation?

Tags: java, collections, singleton-methods

I have tested Collections.singleton() method, how to work, but i see that it is not work as what documentation say?

```
List arraylist= new ArrayList();
arraylist.add("Nguyen");
arraylist.add("Van");
arraylist.add("Jone");
List list = Collections.singletonList(arraylist);// contains three elements
System.out.println(list.size());// right
```

As what documentation say, The method call returns an immutable list containing only the specified object,A singleton list contains only one element and a singleton HashMap includes only one key. A singleton object is immutable (cannot be modified to add one more element),but when what thing i see in my code that list contains three elements("Nguyen","Van","Jone").

Anybody can explain for me why?? Thanks so much !!

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to your documentation? I can't find your source anywhere

Comment: at here @ http://way2java.com/collections/collections-collections/singleton-list-with-singletonlist/. This is good website to learn Java, it is my think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned `List` is a `List` of `List`s. In this case, the returned list of lists itself is immutable, **not** the contained `List`. Also the returned list contains only *one* element, not three: the `arraylist` variable itself is considered an element and is the only element stored in the list returned by `Collections.singletonList`. In other words, the statement `Collections.singletonList(arraylist)` does not create a list that contains all elements of the provided list.

It would have been much more obvious if you use generics:

```
List<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<>();
arraylist.add("Nguyen");
arraylist.add("Van");
arraylist.add("Jone");
List<List<String>> list = Collections.singletonList(arraylist);
```

What the documentation says is that if you do the following:

```
List list = Collections.singletonList(arraylist);
list.add(new ArrayList());
```

then this would throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: i confused that, A singleton list contains only one element. As what things you say then "A singleton list contains only one element" not correct, because one element is not List of List

Comment: @QuanNguyen The returned list only contains _one_ element, which is the `arraylist` itself that is first created. It does not contain three elements.

Comment: @QuanNguyen it's quite simple. Collections.singletonList(Foo foo) returns a List<Foo> containing a single element: the foo passed as argument. You're passing an ArrayList as argument. So Collections.singletonList returns a List containing a single element: the arrayList you passed as argument. It thus returns a List<ArrayList>. The single element is the ArrayList.

Comment: @ Oke, i have understood, it's good  explainations, thanks a lot.

Comment: @QuanNguyen note that generics exist since 2004, and you're still not using them. It would help you if you used them: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); List<List<String>> singleton = Collections.singletonList(list);` See how it's now simple to understand what each list contains.

Comment: @JB Nizet, Thanks for offer. I know generic, i just write simple code to check singletonList, so i does not apply the generic to my  code @@